# Android webview keep caching html files

Tags: android, html, cache-control

I have deployed a single page app in the server, but I notice that Android webview keep caching the `index.html` file, so every time I deploy a new version, the android device won't download the new html file, still using the cache version instead.

my html file

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="app.[hash].js" />
</body>
</html>
```

request headers

```sh
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: xxx
pragma: no-cache
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

notice that I get a `cache-control: no-cache`

response headers

```sh
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html
date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 08:18:34 GMT
etag: W/"5d07418c-e22"
last-modified: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 07:30:20 GMT
server: nginx/1.15.2
status: 200
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help without seeing your Android related code

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the code, the app is one of my target app, is there a way to force no-cache without touching the app related code ?